# Where to subscribe for Redis Pub/Sub in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, redis, publish-subscribe

I've been using [Redis's Pub/Sub](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redis#pubsub) a bit in my application and so far it has been great. I am able to send out a Publish out of Laravel to a different backend process that is able to Subscribe, and eventually Publish an event back to Laravel.

The use case for the user looks like:

submit a form -> wait for a response (a few minutes) -> proceed with transaction

On the backend:

the form posts to a route, then to a controller that publishes this to a subscribed 3rd party (channel one), and eventually that 3rd party publishes back (channel two)

**Main Issue:**  I don't know where the appropriate place to be for subscribing to the (channel two) and processing what gets published there.

Ideally, I'd be able to process Publish requests in two ways:

1. Letting the user know that their form has been processed and they can move onto the next step (probably with an update to a property a Vue component)
2. Storing information from the publish into my database.

In the docs, they have it in a Command, which if I try to use here would look like so:

```
public function handle()
{
    Redis::subscribe('channel-two', function ($message) {
        // update the client so that the user moves on
        // send $message contents to the database
    });
}
```

but that doesn't really seem ideal for me since I want this channel subscribed to 24/7, always listening. Even if it is in a Command, it is still apparent how I would best update the client.

Where in my Laravel project should I be subscribing at? Is there a best practice to respond to these events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Redis::subscribe` is used in a command like in that example for listening on a given channel continuously.

From the docs:

> First, let's setup a channel listener using the  subscribe method. We'll place this method call within an Artisan command since calling the subscribe method begins a **long-running process**:

You'll want to run the command using a process manager like supervisor or pm2, much the same as the docs describe running [queue listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#supervisor-configuration).

Comment: So you would still recommend putting it in a Command? I suppose that works for running it 24/7 which is good. Any idea how I can get that event to update my client-side?

Comment: Yes having it run through a command is how I've run similar services. In order for the event to be received client side, you'll need to run a server that broadcasts the notifications to client subscribed to the appropriate channels. [Laravel Echo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting) is the frameworks offering that handles receiving notifications, while applications like [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server), [pusher](https://pusher.com/) and most recently [laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) handle the broadcasting.

Comment: As an aside, I've recently integrated [laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) into a major project and have been very happy with the results. It is a drop-in replacement for pusher purpose built to work with Laravel. I highly recommend you look into it first.

Comment: Aren’t those all Redis replacements? I feel like Redis pub/sub has done 99% of what I need it to do, so it doesn’t really feel right pulling in a whole different library just to get the Publishes down to client side.

Comment: No, they are websocket libraries for client-server communication. Redis is still an integral part of the system.

Comment: Okay great thanks, I certainly will give [laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) a go. Is Laravel Echo still necessary, or can I just listen via my Pub/Sub in the command, and then update the client with laravel-websockets?